# How to test whether horizontal mouse position is equal to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onmousemove

I'm working on a javascript learning project (no jQuery) and I need to test whether the horzontal position of the mouse is the same value as a variable.

I have a div that follows the mouse around, and when its horizontal position is equal to that of another div, I want to do something.

Here's what I've got:

```
    var x = e.clientX; 

    var otherVar = 200;

    document.getElementById('testDiv').style.left = otherVar + "px";

    if (x == otherVar) {

        //do stuff

    } else {

        //do other stuff

    }
```

I've tested it and it doesnt seem to work, however there are no errors showing up on the console.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: does it have position:absolute?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko The div that follows the mouse is absolute, the other div is relative

Comment: Something like this?
*onmousemove = function(e){
    console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (e.clientX>20 && e.clientX<400) {
        console.log("You got me:", e.clientX,e.clientY);
    }
}*

Comment: @blackpen Yes this could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` expects a string and you need to listen for the `mousemove` event:

This should help point you in the right direction. Good luck.

```js
//define your vars:
var otherDiv = document.getElementById("otherDiv"),
    testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv"),
    otherVar = otherDiv.offsetLeft; //otherDiv's left position in px
//add event listener:
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove);
//handle the event:
function onmousemove(e) {
  var x = e.clientX; //get the current x position
  testDiv.style.left = x + "px"; //move testDiv
  if (x >= otherVar) {
    //do stuff
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    //do other stuff
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background: #eee;
}
#otherDiv {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#testDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="otherDiv">otherDiv</div>
<div id="testDiv">testDiv</div>
```

Comment: yep, I forgot the quotes. just a typo. this is very close to what I'm looking for. I can use it. :) Thanks!

Comment: I changed the statement to  `if (x >= otherVar && x<= otherVar + 100)` That way the div will be green  as long as it is under the blue one, but not if it's on the other side